# Finding Permutation Matrix with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I am looking for the correct permutation matrix that would take matrix a and turn it into matrix b given

```
a = np.array([[1,4,7,-2],[3,0,-2,-1],[-4,2,1,0],[-8,-3,-1,2]])
b = np.array([[-4,2,1,0],[3,0,-2,-1],[-8,-3,-1,2],[1,4,7,-2]])
```

I tried

```
x = np.linalg.solve(a,b)
```

However, I know this is incorrect and it should be

```
np.array([[0,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0]])
```

What numpy code would deliver this matrix from the other two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, if you have some `PA = B` and you want `P` then you need to solve the equation for `P`. Matrix multiplication is not commutative, so you have to *right* multiply both sides by the inverse of `A`. With `numpy`, the function to get the inverse of a matrix is `np.linalg.inv()`.

Using the matrix multiplication operator `@`, you can right-multiply with `b` to get `P`, taking note that you will end up with floating point precision errors:

```py
In [4]: b @ np.linalg.inv(a)
Out[4]:
array([[-1.38777878e-16, -3.05311332e-16,  1.00000000e+00,
        -1.31838984e-16],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  6.93889390e-17,
         0.00000000e+00],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, -1.11022302e-16,
         1.00000000e+00],
       [ 1.00000000e+00, -4.44089210e-16,  5.55111512e-17,
         0.00000000e+00]])
```

As @Mad Physicist points out, you can compare this matrix with `> 0.5` to convert it to a boolean matrix:

```py
In [7]: bool_P = (b @ np.linalg.inv(a)) > 0.5

In [8]: bool_P @ a
Out[8]:
array([[-4,  2,  1,  0],
       [ 3,  0, -2, -1],
       [-8, -3, -1,  2],
       [ 1,  4,  7, -2]])

In [9]: bool_P @ a == b  # our original equation, PA = B
Out[9]:
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

Comment: Instead of rounding, you can check if the result is > 0.5

Comment: Is that more efficient than rounding? I suppose it probably is...

Comment: It's nicer because it gives you a boolean matrix, which is perfect for permutations

Answer (score 3):

`solve` computes `x` in the equation `Ax = B`. You can use it, but the arguments have to match.

Your equation is `XA = B`. You can take the transpose of both sides to get `ATXT = BT`, which has the correct form. So you can get the result from

```
np.linalg.solve(A.T, B.T).T
```

To get a boolean result that's guaranteed to be zeros and ones, you can apply a threshold:

```
np.linalg.solve(A.T, B.T).T > 0.5
```